# SQL printing all in one row

Tags: mysql

I want to print data in two columns, like: 
Count Category

But my code prints all in one row, like:
Count Category Count Category

Any tips?

```
Select sum(Case when population >= 1000000 and population < 5000000 then 1 else 0 end) as Count, '1 000 000 - 4 999 999' as Category,
   sum(Case when population >= 500000 and population < 100000 then 1 else 1 end) as Count, '100 000 - 499 999' as Category,
   sum(Case when population >= 500000 and population < 100000 then 1 else 1 end) as Count, '500 000 - 999 999' as Category,
   sum(Case when population >= 500000 and population < 100000 then 1 else 1 end) as Count, 'Under 100 000' as Category,
   sum(Case when population >= 500000 and population < 100000 then 1 else 1 end) as Count, 'Over 5 million' as Category
from cities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select sum(Case when population >= 1000000 and population < 5000000 then 1 else 0 end) as Count, '1 000 000 - 4 999 999' as Category FROM cities
UNION 
SELECT sum(Case when population >= 500000 and population < 100000 then 1 else 1 end) as Count, '100 000 - 499 999' as Category FROM cities
```

and so on...

Concat all single resuts in one result table with UNION keyword

your else in case part should be everywhere 0 not 1 if you just want to count the cities...
A Better solution anyway would be

```
SELECT COUNT(cities.primKey) as Count, '1 000 000 - 4 999 999' as Category FROM cities WHERE population >= 1000000 and population < 5000000
UNION
SELECT COUNT(cities.primKey) as Count, '1 000 000 - 4 999 999' as Category FROM cities WHERE population >= 500000 and population < 100000
UNION ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Population >= 5000000
            THEN 'Over 5 million' 
            WHEN Population >= 1000000 AND Population < 5000000
            THEN '1 000 000 - 4 999 999'
            WHEN Population >= 500000 AND Population < 1000000
            THEN '500 000 - 999 999' 
            WHEN Population >= 100000 AND Population < 500000
            THEN '100 000 - 499 999'
            WHEN Population < 100000
            THEN 'Under 100 000'
       END [Category]
       ,COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM Cities
```

Comment: I wrote this in T-SQL syntax but I'm not sure there's a difference at this level, so sorry if there is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all categories even if there are no cities that belong to it, you can do:

```
select sum(if(ci.population is null, 0, 1)) as 'Count', cat.Category
from (
  select 0 as 'low', 100000 as 'high', 'Under 100 000' as Category, 1 as 'ord'
  union
  select 100000, 499999, '100 000 - 499 999', 2
  union
  select 500000, 999999, '500 000 - 999 999', 3
  union
  select 1000000, 4999999, '1 000 000 - 4 999 999', 4
  union
  select 5000000, null, 'Over 5 million' , 5
) as cat
  left join cities ci on ci.population between cat.low and ifnull(cat.high, ci.population)
group by cat.Category, cat.ord
order by cat.ord
```